# Android - Mosquitto/MQTT - PHP/MySQL

Tags: web-services, queue, mqtt, mosquitto

I've a question for you. 
I have to implement a queue governing the accesses to a database on Server. 
The Server is in PHP and MySQL. I implemented an Android app to send and store data into DB by WebServices with HTTP Requests.
I thought to use the Mosquitto broker to implement the aforementioned "accessed queue".

First, can I use Mosquitto for this purpose? Furthermore, is it necessary to parse the HTTP Requests in the MQTT Requests and viceversa?

I'm new in MQTT. I know how it works but i don't know how implementing it. Examples in this regard are welcome! :-)
Sorry for my bad English. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should think of MQTT as an alternative for your WebServices implementation.

Typically in MQTT your server will implement an MQTT client library (See a list [here](http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/libraries)) that will subscribe (or publish) to the topics in your Mosquitto broker that your Android App will publish (or subscribe) to.

At the same time your Android App will implement an MQTT client library (Such as Eclipse [Paho Android](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) Service) to subscribe (or publish) to the topics in the same Mosquitto broker.